# copyFile with node occasionally only copies part of file

Tags: node.js, copy, fs, chokidar

I'm trying to build a file watcher that copies files when they are finally added using `chokidar`. The files have differing sizes, but range between 200MB and 1GB.

```js
watch(`${inputFolder}/*/**`, {
    ignoreInitial: false,
    awaitWriteFinish: true,
}).on("add", (path) => {
    handleFileAdded(path);
    retryFailedPaths();
});
```

I'm having a weird issue where some files are only being copied partly and then left there without any errors. The target size differs and is not constant. I get the feeling that somehow the process is being interrupted by something. Strangely the code after the (corrupted) copying happily continues, in this case remove the source file.

```js
fs.copyFileSync(sourcePath, newPath, fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE);
fs.unlinkSync(sourcePath);
```

From that I conclude that the process itself is not being killed. I'm also observing that `chokidar` fires faster than previous files could copy but I assumed that not being a problem since the files have nothing to do with each other.

I tried `fs.copySync` and `fs.promises.copy`, both of which have the same behaviour. I couldn't reproduce this locally, most likely because my computer is faster than the target environment. I also had a look at resource usage on the target device but it never reached the cap neither RAM- nor CPU-wise. On the target device the files are being copied from one hard drive to another though.

Here are some extra information:

environment: docker

runtime: node14:alpine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy. The file was added and registered by `chokidar` before it was completely written to disk. That way, the copyFileSync overwrote the target file anytime a new "update" was registered by `chokidar`.